# x axis value not correct for ggplot scatter plot with a single point

Tags: python, python-ggplot

I'm using ggplot with a pandas dataframe to produce a scatter plot with a coloured factor. It's working as expected for multiple points but when I have a single point as input the x axis value is not as expected.

It works as expected with (say) a ggplot of 2 points:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0]], columns=(['a', 'b']))
print df
print ggplot(df, aes(x='a', y='b')) + geom_point()
```

But not for a single point:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1.0, 2.0]], columns=(['a', 'b']))
print df
print ggplot(df, aes(x='a', y='b')) + geom_point()
```

This gives:

```
   a  b
0  1  2
```

[ggplot output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJIKE.png)

The x axis is showing that a is at 0.005. With the x axis scale (?) set to '+9.95e-1'.

I tried this simple example in R and it worked as expected, with the point at b=2 and a=1, with simple units for each axis.

I tried setting the geom_point(stat='identity') but this made no difference.

Am I missing something obvious about the way ggplot works when dealing with a single point? Do I need to force the scale / transformation on the x axis? If yes how do I do this so that it works for multiple and single points?